# Ngrx 6.1.0 - Select is deprecated - What is the new syntax?

Tags: ngrx

The following ngrx select is deprecated.

```
this.store.select(state => state.academy.academy).subscribe((academy) => {
    this.academy = academy;
});
```

I found this at store.d.ts

```
@deprecated from 6.1.0. Use the pipeable `select` operator instead.
```

So... what's the correct syntax?

I try

```
this.store.pipe(select(state => state.academy.academy).subscribe((academy) => {
    this.academy = academy;
}))
```

Error:  Cannot find name 'select'. Did you mean 'onselect'?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Store, select} from '@ngrx/store';
import {AppState} from '../../../../../app.state';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-layout',
   templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./layout.component.scss']
})
export class PageLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

   academy;

   constructor(
      private store: Store<AppState>
   ) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.store.pipe(select((state: any) => state.academy.academy)).subscribe((academy) => {
         this.academy = academy;
      });
   }


}
```

Comment: Seems like per @timdeschryver's answer, it's undeprecated. Some reasons included that the method is easier to mock and test, which is something to consider when using the pipeable operator instead.

Answer (score 24):

As per NgRx 7, the `select` method is un-deprecated.

For more info, see the associated [Pull Request](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1361).

Answer (score 8):

As @Michalis mentioned, just get `select` from `@ngrx/store`.

> Selectors empower you to compose a read model for your application state. In terms of the CQRS architectural pattern, NgRx separates the read model (selectors) from the write model (reducers). An advanced technique is to combine selectors with RxJS pipeable operators.

This feature was added in [v5.0.0](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-6), and since then `this.store.select()` has been deprecated. However, notice for the same is added in release v6.1.0. As `Store<T>` itself extends `Observable<T>`, it returns observable which can easily be subscribed using `.subscribe()` or can be manipulated/transformed using different patch operators.

RxJS introduced pipable operators  and `.pipe()` in [v5.5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). There is also a pipe utility function that can be used to build reusable pipeable operators. In release v5, with the help of `pipe()` custom `select` operator is built. Check out this [link](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md#advanced-usage) or basic example(ignore empty state) is given beneath, to learn more.

```
import { select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const selectFilteredState = pipe(
  select('sliceOfState'),
  filter(state => state !== undefined)
);

store.pipe(selectFilteredState ).subscribe(/* .. */);
```