# Angular 6 ng lint select is deprecated

Tags: angular6, ngrx, rxjs6

I got the tslint waring `select is deprecated: from 6.1.0. Use the pipeable
'select' operator instead.`

my selectors looks like below

`private availableStudents$ = this.store.select(getAvailableStudents);`

also my package.json

`"rxjs": "^6.0.0"
"tslint": "~5.9.1"
"typescript": "^2.9.2"
"@angular/cli": "~6.1.2`

Comment: Can you post code snippet here so it would be good to get more idea OR have a look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672633/ngrx-6-1-0-select-is-deprecated-what-is-the-new-syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
private availableStudents$ = this.store.pipe(select(getAvailableStudents));
```

The above uses the pipeable operator as suggested in the warning.

And be sure to import it:

```
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
```

Comment: could you tell me what's the benefit of if we use pipeable operator?

Comment: They can be better tree shaken. See this for more info: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/876