# How to test guards in Angular 7 ngrx 6.1

Tags: angular, unit-testing, redux, karma-jasmine, ngrx

We used Angular 5 and updated it to 7.
At the moment store select wripes in pipe();

Some unit tests are failing:

```js
export class MyGuard  {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
   
    this.store.dispatch(new Action());
    return this.store.pipe(
      select<IAppState>(getMainState),
      map((state: IState) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/', url]);
      }),
      catchError((a, b) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/', 'error']);
        return of(false);
      }),
    );
  }
```

And unit test:

```js
 it('should redirect to page ', inject(
    [MyGuard, Service],
    (guard: MyGuard, service: Service) => {
      spyOn(service, 'method').and.callFake(b => of({ id: { status: 'ok'} }));

      const route = new ActivatedRouteSnapshot();
      route.params = { id: '2' };
      const activation = guard.canActivate(route, {
        root: null,
        url: 'url',
      });

      if (activation instanceof Observable) {
        activation.subscribe(activationValue => {
          expect(activationValue).toBe(false);
expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });
      } else {
        fail('should not happen - should return an observable with true');
      }
    },
  ));
```

And we get fail, because activation (guard.canActivate) not Observable. Could some help and tell how to refactor unit tests according to new ngrx ?

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a few problems with what you have posted.

**Update:** Originally I thought you were using the old rxjs select, but that was incorrect.  Do be sure your are using the select from ngrx with an import like this:

`import { select } from '@ngrx/store';`

If you require `canActivate()` to return an Observable, then don't declare it like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
```

but rather declare it like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
```

Another problematic section is this:

```
map((state: IState) => {
     this.router.navigate(['/', url]);
}),
```

First of all, it doesn't return anything, so it breaks the observable chain - perhaps the easiest fix there is simply removing the curly braces so it returns the value from `this.router.navigate()`.  But - there is the second problem in this section: `this.router.navigate` returns a promise, not an observable, so if you want to use it in an observable chain you need to wrap it with `from`.  Lastly since this is itself an Observable and returns an Observable, you'll want to use an operator such as `mergeMap`, or `switchMap` depending on your needs.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do within the `catchError`, so I left that alone, but you'll want to test this out in case of error to be sure it is functioning as you expect.

I also found your current indentation quite confusing.

Lastly, you didn't post details on what `this.store` looks like in your particular implementation.  Be sure it returns an observable!  :)

Put that all together and one possible refactor could look like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    this.store.dispatch(new Action());
    return this.store.pipe(
        select<IAppState>(getMainState),
        mergeMap((state: IState) => 
            from(this.router.navigate(['/', url]))
        ),
        catchError((a, b) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/', 'error']);
            return of(false);
        }),
    );
}
```

I am less than 50% confident this will work as-is however, because of all the unknowns I detailed above.  I hope this helps at least point you in the right direction of finding an answer.

Comment: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672633/ngrx-6-1-0-select-is-deprecated-what-is-the-new-syntax) which shows I gave the wrong advice regarding changing map to select.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that.  Also in that post it recommends importing select like this: `import { select } from '@ngrx/store';`. Is that how you are doing it?